# How to insert depending LINQ to SQL entities without manual ID update in C#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, insert

I have 2 models.

Model **Foo**

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = ...)]
public class Foo
{
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
  public int BarID { get; set; }
  
  // 1:1 association - foo <> bar
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Name = "FK_Foo_Bar", Storage = "mBar", OtherKey = "ID", ThisKey = "BarID")]
  public Bar CurrentRevision
  {
    get { return mBar.Entity; }
    set { mBar.Entity = value; }
  }
  
  private System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Bar> mBar = new System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Bar>();
}
```

Model **Bar**

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = ...)]
public class Bar
{
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
  public int FooID { get; set; }
  
  // 1:1 association - bar <> foo
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Name = "FK_Bar_Foo", Storage = "mFoo", OtherKey = "ID", ThisKey = "FooID")]
  public Foo Folder
  {
    get { return mFoo.Entity; }
    set { mFoo.Entity = value; }
  }
  
  private System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Foo> mFoo = new System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Foo>();
}
```

I want to insert a **Foo** and a **Bar** like so

```
lFoo = new Foo();
DataContext.Foos.InsertOnSubmit(lFoo);    

lBar = new Bar();
DataContext.Bars.InsertOnSubmit(lBar);    

lBar.Foo = lFoo; // link foo to bar
lFoo.Bar = lBar; // link bar to foo

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

A row for `lFoo` and a row for `lBar` is added to the DB but the `FooID` and `BarID` field remains zero.

Is there a way to let the framework update column `FooID` and `BarID` with the correct IDs automatically instead of doing this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issues causes this as i found out by reading the [LINQ to SQL documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) on MSDN:

1. multiple `IsPrimaryKey` in one class indicates a composite key, the DB does not have one
2. the `IsForeignKey` attribute is missing
3. linking the objects bidirectionaly directly after the `InsertOnSubmits()` calls won't work as it raises a [A cycle was detected in the set of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18141834/3936440) exception.

So the correct way would be

Model **Foo**

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = ...)]
public class Foo
{
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
  public int BarID { get; set; }

  // 1:1 association - foo <> bar
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Name = "FK_Foo_Bar", Storage = "mBar", OtherKey = "ID",
    ThisKey = "BarID", IsForeignKey=true)]
  public Bar CurrentRevision
  {
    get { return mBar.Entity; }
    set { mBar.Entity = value; }
  }

  private System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Bar> mBar = new System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Bar>();
}
```

Model **Bar**

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = ...)]
public class Bar
{
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
  public int FooID { get; set; }

  // 1:1 association - bar <> foo
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Name = "FK_Bar_Foo", Storage = "mFoo", OtherKey = "ID",
    ThisKey = "FooID", IsForeignKey=true)]
  public Foo Folder
  {
    get { return mFoo.Entity; }
    set { mFoo.Entity = value; }
  }

  private System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Foo> mFoo = new System.Data.Linq.EntityRef<Foo>();
}
```

Inserts

```
lFoo = new Foo();
DataContext.Foos.InsertOnSubmit(lFoo);    

lBar = new Bar();
DataContext.Bars.InsertOnSubmit(lBar);    

DataContext.SubmitChanges();    

lBar = lFoo; // link foo to bar
lFoo = lBar; // link bar to foo

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

As a side node, sadly, using the `IsForeignKey` attribute value alters the query behavior (e.g. LINQ to SQL generates CROSS JOINS instead of INNER JOINS) and overall program logic in my case.